# Valid SSL Certificate should always create a Secure Connection?

Tags: ssl, https

If you have a valid SSL certificate should you always have a 'Secure Connection' validation from a browser? When I say 'Secure Connection' validation I mean the green padlock in the below image.

[image]

Are there other things that can 'fail'/deprive a website of this 'Secure Connection' validation? For example; does an error in a 3rd party javascript file fail your website (for a Secure Connection)? Do other things influence the 'Secure Connection'?

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of reasons why the green padlock may not appear which indicates the browser could not securely load the page according to the browsers security standards. the most common is mixed content i.e you've loaded some images/scripts etc over http rather than https.

Here is in a good article:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1057/0/why-isnt-my-sites-padlock-green-or-doesnt-have-green-address-bar

There's plenty of material available on a quick google search

Comment: Whilst "link only" answers are discouraged, in this instance it's appropriate as there is little value to be gained by copy/pasting the wealth of info already available